# How to aspect fit the bar button image

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add the image in the navigation bar button.

Here is the image I want to set:

[image]

I set it by drag the `bar button` to the `Main.storyboard`. Then I set it like this:

```
@IBOutlet var addNewNoteButton: UIBarButtonItem!

...

let featherImageView = UIImageView()
featherImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

featherImageView.image = UIImage(named: "feather")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
addNewNoteButton.image = featherImageView.image
```

But it doesn't show the image well:

[image]'

I also see somewhere, but they only do with create a button, then assign this button to navigation bar button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom button for that. Use below code in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
//create a new button
let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)

//set image for button
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "T018d.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

//set frame
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 31)

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

//assign button to navigationbar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

And result will be:

[image]

If you want to place it left side then replace this line

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

with

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: I know this solution, but I don't know why my code doesn't work. Can you check it again.

Comment: I think the easy way is resizing the image outside xcode :). It work well now.

Comment: Just letting you know `Custom` has been changed to `custom` and `Normal` to `normal`. Swift will throw an error and change it for you.

Answer (score 5):

The solution Swift 4:

```
let barButton = UIButton()

self.backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "image"), for: .normal)
backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "image"), for: .highlighted)
backButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PresenterBaseViewController.backAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

barButton.addSubview(self.backButton)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: barButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let addNewNoteButtonImage = UIImage(named: "feather")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)

addNewNoteButton.image = addNewNoteButtonImage
addNewNoteButton.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the set the content mode of an UIImage in a UIButton you have to access the buttons imageView with:

```
button(UIImage(named: "feather"), forState: .Normal)
button?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```