# Navigation bar button image coming out pixelated

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a `UIImage` for my left bar button on my navigation controller.  In the design file the button is 40X40px.  This ends up being too big to be used for the button.  As seen below:

[image]

[image]

I reduced the button down to 16px and now I get something like this:

[image]

I can't seem to get the size right for the button to look clear.  I've tried 28px-10px.  Any advice?

EDIT Added 10px, 20px, and 30px of image

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code for setting button

```
var settingsImage = UIImage(named: "SettingsButton10px.png")
settingsImage = settingsImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
let settingsButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: settingsImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(HomeController.settingsPressed))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsButton
```

Comment: Are you providing the `@2x` and `@3x` images as well?

Comment: @AdilSoomro not yet.  I'm just running this on the iphone 5 simulator.  Do I need to?

Comment: You should add 2x and 3x images too. Yes even for simulator you need that. Retina Mac with iphone 5 simulator uses 2x image. (i think around 22, 44, 66 px should be ok)

Answer (score 1):

In your projects `Assets.xcassets`, create an `Image Set` and provide @1x, @2x and @3x versions. So if the original image size is 20x20, you also need a 40x40, and a 60x60.

Then, when you reference the image in a `UIImage`, do it with the name of the Image set from the `Assets.xcassets` without the file extensions. So if the name of the `ImageSet` in `Assets.xcassets` was `SettingsIcon`, you would load the image like so:

`UIImage(named: "SettingsIcon")`

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem.  I have a 10px, 20px, and 40px version of the image file and it still comes out pixelated.  Do I need a bigger version of the image?

Comment: You should have 10x, 20x, and 30x, not 40x

Comment: I edited question to include 10px, 20px, and 30px versions.  All pixelated.

Comment: Please add the code where you are setting the `navigationItem`

Answer (score 1):

If adding @2x & @3x image size does't helped you why can't we go with **Vector pdf..?** Here is what i have got

1. You can get **PDF images** from [here,](https://icons8.com/web-app/for/all/settings)Change the image formate from **PNG** to **PDF**.[image]
2. Then in drag and drop the downloaded pdf image in **Assets.xcassets**. Then Change **Scale Factors** to **Single Vector**

[image]

3.Make sure **Image set** look like this

[image]

4. Since we added the image in **Assets** no need to add extension so replace this

   ```
   var settingsImage = UIImage(named: "SettingsButton10px.png")
   ```

   with

   ```
   var settingsImage = UIImage(named: "SettingsButton10px")
   ```

**RESUT:**

- Using PNG **25px**:

[image]

- Using PDF **25px**:

[image]

So now no need to add double and triple sized images,**Pixalation** issue will be fixed when we use PDF.

Comment: Interesting.  Never considered using a PDF.  Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has some information on custom icon sizes here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/

The size you want for an iPhone 5 is "About 44px by 44px," so you've got that in the right ballpark. It's a matter of making sure iOS knows this is a retina resolution asset.

The easiest way to do this is putting it in an "Image Set" inside `Assets.xcassets`. These are containers for multiple different scales, and allow iOS to pick the appropriate version for a given device and display it without pixelation.

The "1x" scale was used in pre-retina devices, "2x" is most common (and is what you'll need to set for the iPhone 5 simulator), and "3x" is for iPhone 6 Plus sized phone.

If you haven't created the 3x image yet, it's fine to leave it blank for now.

Comment: I understand.  However, I think the issue has to do with UIBarButton scaling the image.  The first screenshot in my post is using a 40px image and its pixelated and far too big.  All pixel sizes less than 40 come out more and more pixelated.

Comment: Never done any testing on this myself, but my assumption is that it takes your image, sees that it's not marked as a 2x size image, and goes "Well this 40x40 is way too big to use in a toolbar. Toolbar images should only be ~22x22 pixels!"

Then it scales that down to fit and displays it as an 1x image asset.

Comment: How come when I use the 20px version of my image it still looks incorrect?

Comment: Because it's being displayed at double size. Notice how the pixels in your status bar (wifi, battery, etc.) are smaller than the pixels in your icon. A 22x22ish icon size is what you'd have used on a pre-retina iPhone, so it's taking that 20px icon and blowing it up to 40 physical pixels on screen. The pixelation really stands out when you put it alongside retina graphics.

Comment: To clarify a bit on Apple's handling of retina devices, the pixel dimensions that you see in Xcode are all based on pre-retina screens. The finer detail that retina adds is handled as fractions of pixels. 

So if you're putting a retina image on an object that Xcode calls "20 px" tall, the physical dimension of that image file should be 40 pixels for most current devices. But for the same image on an iPhone 6 Plus, you'd need a version that's 60 pixels.

Comment: And the naming convention used in iOS for it to automatically find these images is appending `@2x` or `@3x` on the filename. If you want to load an image named `myButton.png`, you'd make additional larger copies named `myButton@2x.png` and `myButton@3x.png`, then when it goes to find the file it should grab the correct size for the screen it's running on.  But the "image sets" in Xcode are a convenient UI for setting these groups up.

Comment: I agree with everything you're saying.  But I think there is something specific about providing an image to a UIBarButton that is beyond just providing the correct retina images. I was able to get it to work by implementing the first answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876477/how-to-aspect-fit-the-bar-button-image